# Limit to Maximum Number of Nodes on Corda Network

Tags: corda

In my Corda Use Case, I could potentially have 3,000-4,000 participants on my network. My original thought was to have one node per participant.  If I were to do that, can Corda handle that make participants?(from a performance standpoint) or is there way to have multiple participants on a single node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no maximum number of nodes on a network, although the platform hasn't officially been tested to those numbers (it has been tested to around 500). There could plausibly be an impact on memory footprint (i.e. each node might need a bit more memory to cope).

For sufficiently high transaction rates, the notary could eventually become a bottleneck. Corda's notary implementations are continuing to improve, and are already in the high 100s of transactions per second. You could also have multiple notaries on the same network.